# Reading TCP data from camera stops after a specific amount of pictures

Tags: .net, vb.net, networking, tcp

I'm reading data via TCP from a camera, I first send a trigger via TCP to take a picture, next I read the camera image. Everything works fines until 296 triggers done, from that moment the program is blocked at the first TCP read.

I can temporary fix this by sending again a trigger (from another program). I believe at that moment the camera is triggered 2 times (possibly the blocked one and the new trigger (to fix)).

Anybody have an idea what could go wrong? Thank you!

```
    'Code in Timer
    'Trigger
    Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
    tcpClient.Connect("ip", port)
    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
    If networkStream.CanWrite Then
        networkStream.Write(dataTrigger, 0, n)
        tcpClient.Close()
    Else

        If Not networkStream.CanWrite Then
            Console.WriteLine("cannot read data from this stream")
            tcpClient.Close()
        End If
    End If
    networkStream.Close()

    'Read images
    Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
    tcpClient.Connect("ip", port)
    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
    If networkStream.CanRead Then
        ' Reading data length
        Dim dataLength(15) As Byte
        networkStream.Read(dataLength, 0, 16)

        ' Reading all data
        Dim bytesReaded, bytesLeft, bytesCounter As Integer
        bytesCounter = 0
        bytesLeft = dataLength
        Do While bytesLeft > 0
            bytesReaded = networkStream.Read(dataImages, bytesCounter, bytesLeft)
            bytesCounter = bytesCounter + bytesReaded
            bytesLeft = dataLengthInt - bytesCounter
        Loop
        tcpClient.Close()
    Else
        If Not networkStream.CanRead Then
            Console.WriteLine("cannot not write data to this stream")
            tcpClient.Close()
        End If
    End If
    networkStream.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`networkStream.Read(dataLength, 0, 16)` is not guaranteed to read all of the data in a single read. you need to loop till you have 16 bytes just like you do with your main loop.

Also you do `bytesLeft = dataLengthInt - bytesCounter` but no where in you code do you assign a value to `dataLengthInt`.

I don't know if you have other errors, (I don't know VB.NET that well) but those two where the biggest ones that jumped out.

Comment: Thank you, this can be a reason, allthough I think this wouldn't block the function. The dataLengthInt conversion is left out.